# Time data ValueError depending on system

Tags: python, datetime

I'm running my Python 3.6 code on a MacOS, which works fine. However, when deploying it to a Linux OS it fails with the following error:

`ValueError: time data 'Nov 5 2018 08:35AM EST' does not match format '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p %Z'`

I've looked through http://strftime.org/ and the format looks good to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Interesting to be good on MAC. There is a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue22377

Comment: Wow, that's insane. How can that bug still be around since 2014?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would never have guessed that such a bug could exist.